# ShinyAPP Covid Data (How to filter and sort?)

Tags: r, ggplot2, shinyapps

I am building a shinyApp to display COVID-19 data. I have a file in long format that displays the day, county, positive cases, recoveries, and deaths. I am attempting to make the app where a user can select a county from a drop down menu and it will display 3 graphs of positives, recoveries, and deaths on the page. The graphs will have x-axis be dates and y-axis as a variable. Attached is the script I have so far. I have tried many different approachers, but I have no idea what to do. I am still learning R and have no prior experience with ShinyApp. Any advice or help would be appreciated. I think I have the ggPlot and output/UI right, the server logic is what is throwing me for a loop. Even just a link to a good guide would be nice. Thanks!

7/23/2020: I have updated the code. I looked in ggplot some. When I run the app, I now have the dropdown menu I wanted, but the graphs are displaying. When I create the ggplot in the console to make sure the code works on its own, I am missing the middle protion of the graph? Any ideas/fixes?

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)
library(plotly)
library(ggplot2)
library(rsconnect)


df <- read.csv("C:/Users/Nathan May/Desktop/Research Files (ABI)/Covid/Data For Shiny/Appended_File/Appended_Scraped_Files.csv") #INSERT PATH SINGLE FILE OPTION

datapos <- df[c(2,6,3)]

rsconnect::setAccountInfo(name='nathanjmay', token='A3CF4CC3DE0112B8B9F8D0BA429223D3', secret='TNwC9hxwZt+BffOhFaXD3FQsMg3eQnfaPGr0eE8S')

#UI

ui <- fluidPage(
titlePanel("COVID-19 in Arkansas Counties"),
  fluidRow(
    column(
      width=4,
      selectizeInput("County", label=h5("County"), choices= data$Counties, width="100%")
    )),
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput(outputId = "Positive")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput(outputId = "Recoveries")
  ),
  fluidRow(
    plotOutput(outputId = "Deaths")
  ),)
  
#SERVER

server= function(input, output) {

  data <- reactive({
    datapos %>% filter(County == input$County)
  
#GGPLOT2 for Positive
  output$Positive -> renderPlot(ggplot(data=datapos, aes(x=Day, y=Positive)) + 
                                geom_bar(stat="identity"))

#Recoveries
  output$Recoveries -> renderplot()

#Deaths
  output$Deaths -> renderplot()
  })
  }


shinyApp(ui=ui, server=server)
```

Comment: You may need `datapos %>% filter(County == input$County)` inside the server and the `ggplot` the `P` is not upper case

Comment: @akrun Your suggestion worked! Now if only I could get it to display the graph. I have updated the code in the above question if you have any ideas? I am also getting thefolowing error on app start:  Error in data$Counties : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable

Answer (score 0):

You're assigning all reactive expressions to the `data` object in the server logic, look at where you close the curly bracket. So everything get wrapped into `data` and nothing about your `plotOutput`, i.e. `output$Positive`, `output$Recoveries`, `output$Death` are specified in your server logic. Also the way to use `reactive()` feel a little awkward at first. Here's my super simply app to illustrate what you ought to do wrt to using `reactive()`. Again notice where you open and close the curly bracket and parentheses.

So the chain of reactions defined here are: `input$state` >> `dat` via `reactive()` >> `output$dummy` via `renderPlot()`.

```
library(shiny)
library(dplyr)
library(ggplot2)

#### Fake data
df <- data.frame(state = rep(c("FL", "GA"), each = 2),
                 x = rnorm(4),
                 y = rnorm(4))

#### UI
ui <- fluidPage(
    titlePanel("Old Faithful Geyser Data"),
    sidebarLayout(
        selectInput("state", "Choose a state:",
                    list(`Florida` = "FL",
                         `Georgia` = "GA")
        ),

        mainPanel(
           plotOutput("dummy")
        )
    )
)

#### Server
server <- function(input, output) {
    ## Essential dat is the filtered df
    dat <- reactive({
        df %>%
            filter(state == input$state)
    })
    
    ## Use dat() to access the filtered df instead of dat
    output$dummy <- renderPlot({
      ggplot(dat()) +
            geom_point(aes(x = x, y = y))
    })
}

# Run the application 
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: I followed your suggestions. I am now receiving an error that says, 'Error in data$Counties : object of type 'closure' is not subsettable'  This appears the be the result of faulty definitions of variables. I fail to see where the issue is now... just my luck! It had worked fine earlier!

Comment: Got a code snippet so I can see what you were doing?

I suspect you need to do dat()$Counties (Note the parentheses behind dat). when you define dat <- reactive(...), dat becomes a "function", and when you try to do something about a function, you get the type 'closure' not subsettable error. Use dat() to retrieve what's inside dat.